# Why I can not use my variable in WHERE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I declare a variable `user_name` so that other people can change it to run my script on their laptop. Here `C##AKIRA` is my account I created in SQL Plus.

```
DECLARE
    user_name    varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    user_name := 'C##AKIRA';
END;
```

When I run

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    all_tables
WHERE
    owner = user_name
```

Oracle returns an error `ORA-00904: "USER_NAME": invalid identifier`. On the other hand, it works well when I run

```
SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    all_tables
WHERE
    owner = 'C##AKIRA'
```

Could you please elaborate on this issue?

```
-- Declare a variable called 'user_name'
DECLARE
    user_name    varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    user_name := 'C##AKIRA';
END;

-- Drop a table of it already exists
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE works_in';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;

-- Create a table called `works_in`
CREATE TABLE works_in (
    coded       NUMBER(2),
    codew       NUMBER(2),
    datewi      DATE,
    hourcount   NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (coded, codew, datewi),
    FOREIGN KEY (coded) REFERENCES doctors (coded),
    FOREIGN KEY (codew) REFERENCES wards (codew)
);

SELECT
    table_name
FROM
    all_tables
WHERE
    owner = user_name
```

Comment: The variable is only defined in the block from `begin` to `end`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there anyway that I can define it globally so that I can use it throughout my script?

Comment: In this context, I suspect what you really want to use are substitution variables, https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-DD1BE849-0B66-4F99-83D0-F3B9F5A0D361

Comment: @LEAnhDung If you must, you could store that value in a temp table and use that temp table as an uncorrelated subquery in the where clause.

Comment: Thank you so much @PhilCoulson. It makes sense.

Comment: @LEAnhDung If you go this route, make sure to keep a mechanism in place where the temp table is either recreated or is truncated and repopulated when other users change that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the variable user_name apply only for :

```
DECLARE
 user_name    varchar2(20);
BEGIN
 user_name := 'C##AKIRA';
END;
```

You must declare the variable only inside pls method you will use.

Like this:

```
-- Declare a variable called 'user_name'
DECLARE
    user_name    varchar2(20);
    v_table_name varchar2(100);
BEGIN
    user_name := 'C##AKIRA';

 SELECT
 table_name
 into v_table_name 
 FROM
 all_tables
 WHERE
 owner = user_name
 and rownum = 1
 ;
END;
```